Shouldn't the Chromatic polynomial be minimized?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661984/question-about-chromatic-polynomial-of-certain-graphs#:~:text=However%2C%20now%20consider%20the%20square,2(%CE%BB%E2%88%922).
In this question, for a graph of a square (n cycle graph with 4 vertices) they have taken two cases:

If we want to properly k-color G, then 1 can be colored anything, so there are k choices for it. Now the color on 2 and 4 have to be different from the color assigned to 1, so there are k−1 choices for each. There are two cases to consider: if the colors of 2 and 4 are the same, then the color for 3 has k − 1 choices. If they’re not the same, then the color for 3 has k − 2 choices.

But shouldn't there be only the case of the opposite vertices being of same color as it is minimum as well as satisfies the condition of coloring? why even consider two of those vertices having different colors, and if it is considered, then why not every color be different?

The chromatic polynomial $\chi_G(k)$ counts the number of proper $k$-colorings of a graph $G$.
In your example of the cycle $C_4$ on four vertices, there are colorings where vertex $2$ and $4$ have the same color and colorings where they differ. Both of these need to be counted.
Maybe you are interested in the chromatic number $\chi(G)$, that is the minimum $k\geq 0$ such that $\chi_G(k)$ is positive. In that case, it is in your interest to color $2$ and $4$ the same, to only use two colors in total, i.e. $\chi(C_4)\leq 2$.

Thank you so much, I was confused between the chromatic polynomial and the chromatic number. I understand that we need to consider all the mutually exclusive possibilities while calculating the former.
